# Unable to specify path to envoy ejection log

Tags: yaml, istio, envoyproxy

In the envoy documentation, it is written that you can specify the path to the ejection log
https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/bootstrap/v3/bootstrap.proto#envoy-v3-api-field-config-bootstrap-v3-clustermanager-outlier-detection

However, I don't understand exactly which path to specify.
I just paste "event.json" there
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c9WH.png)

But when I run the docker file, I get a file access error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ8zR.png)

Tell me how to avoid this?

Comment: Perhaps you should set it to something like /var/log/envoy/events.log ?

Comment: Or perhaps this issue : https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/13241

Comment: Yes, thank you Peter. This issue helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get access, you need to specify **ENVOY_UID = 0**.

In my case, I used docker-compose, so I needed to specify **ENVOY_UID=0** in the environment.

As for the problem of opening and viewing the file, it solved in another question at the link:[Envoy statistics. How to open a file inside Envoy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70800707/envoy-statistics-how-to-open-a-file-inside-envoy)