# How to open a file inside Envoy. Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, envoyproxy

I use docker-compose to run envoy, I need to look at the statistics that will be generated **by outlier_detection** for this in cluster_manager I specified the path in

**event_log_path: /var/log/event.log**

However, I can't figure out how can I open this file to view it? Using volume in docker compose doesn't help

Comment: Have you tried? **docker exec -ti my_container sh -c "cat /var/log/event.log"**

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are suggesting to abandon docker-compose and work with a container?

Comment: docker composer will help you to get up and running all, but you can get access to the containers individually.

Comment: Yes, it helped, thanks. Is it possible to open a file in a non-console format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

1. Displaying the info

`docker exec -ti my_container sh -c "cat /var/log/event.log"`

2. Copying the file to the host

`docker ps`

`docker cp Your_container_ID:/var/log/event.log /my_host_folder`

And editing the file in your host.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. I appreciate your help

Comment: Mark it as answer if that's what was needed it,